# What is the best way to send email reports from Kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I've setup an ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) stack and created some Kibana dashboard widgets. So far everything went amazing. Now I want to send daily and weekly email with the generated reports.

What is the best way to do that. Do I need to install any plugin or I can sent it right from Kibana?

Comment: This is [not available at the moment](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1640).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ElastAlert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert). You will be able to mail a link with the Kibana dashboard with only the data of the period you want. The period parameter in the top right corner will be set automatically in Kibana.

Comment: Yes, it seems cool. However, scheduled email with the details of a dashboard / visualization data is what I am looking for. The data don't need to be graphical, tabular data will also work.

Comment: You can make any dashboard you want in Kibana. A graphical or a tabular one is possible. In ElastAlert you can use any dashboard you have made in Kibana. You can easily write your own rule to make ElastAlert send every week/day a link to you. 
So what do you need more? * There are no offline possibilities in ElastAlert. ElastAlert will always link to your Kibana dashboard

Comment: Ok, I get it, I thought it will only alert on a certain event with visualization link but data. Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @JeroenVandevelde can you please answer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533398/how-to-render-sample-data-inside-a-custom-plugin-of-kibana

Answer (score 2):

There are some workarounds, such as [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) but not straightforward to implement. For specific events and Kibana queries there are alerting mechanisms available (Watcher, Logz.io), but I'm guessing you're looking to receive the entire dashboard by email.

Answer (score 1):

There are two out-of-the box options for sending email reports from Kibana dashboard:

1. [Skedler](https://www.skedler.com) which allows you to schedule and send automated email reports based on your Kibana dashboard or search.
2. If you have Elasticsearch license/subscription, then you can use the reporting plugin.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sentinl](https://github.com/sirensolutions/sentinl) that extends Kibana for Alerting and Reporting functionality to monitor, notify and report on data series changes using standard queries, programmable validators and a variety of configurable actions - Think of it as a free an independent "Watcher" which also has scheduled "Reporting" capabilities (PNG/PDFs snapshots).

The greatest thing about Sentinl is you can easily configure alerts through it's native App interface integrated in Kibana.